# ClassNotFoundException after converting to Maven builds on Struts DynaValidatorForm

Tags: maven, struts, classnotfoundexception

I recently setup Maven on my Struts web project and after deploying the resulting EAR to Websphere Application Server, I'm getting ClassNotFoundExceptions on Struts' DynaValidatorForm class.  This doesn't seem to be JAR related, so I feel like this is concerned with maven creating class files which are not compatible with the version of struts I'm using, although I get no compile-time errors.

Potential clues:

- The DynaValidatorForm class is present in the struts-1.1 jar file which is included in the EAR in the WEB-INF/lib directory.
- Just to make sure I don't have dependency problems caused by the maven conversion, I replaced all the jars in the EAR with all the previous jars (pre-maven, and pre-broken), and I got the *same error* when I deployed that updated EAR with all the old jars (same source code by the way).
- Next, I tried swapping the resulting class files instead of swapping the jars; I replaced all the class files which reference DynaValidatorForm in the maven-built EAR with those same classes from the non-maven-built EAR, and I got NO ERRORS when I installed it in Websphere.  The non-maven-built EAR was built using a simple EAR export from Rational Application Developer (Eclipse).

The fact that the class-swap works makes me feel like the problem is with the class files generated by maven, but I don't know what the issue is.  Java version differences are the only thing I can think of then, but Struts worked fine with Java 5 with my old build process, and I am, or believe I am anyway, building the source code with maven using 1.5 as I have a maven-compiler-plugin defined with source and target set to 1.5.  I'm baffled.

Does anyone have any ideas here?  Thank you so much for any suggestions you may have.

UPDATE:

Interesting pieces of the POM:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
<groupId>com.abc</groupId>
<artifactId>app</artifactId>
<packaging>war</packaging>
<version>1.0.4</version>
<name>app</name>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>struts</groupId>
        <artifactId>struts</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    ... more unrelated dependencies ...
</dependencies>
<build>
    <resources>
        <resource>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
            <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
        </resource>
        <resource>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
            <directory>src/main/java</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**</include>
            </includes>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </resource>
    </resources>
    <testResources>
        <testResource>
            <filtering>false</filtering>
            <directory>src/test/java</directory>
            <includes>
                <include>**</include>
            </includes>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </testResource>
    </testResources>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <inherited>true</inherited>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.5</source>
                <target>1.5</target>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.mortbay.jetty</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-jetty-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-eclipse-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <downloadSources>true</downloadSources>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
</project>
```

Stack Trace:

```
[6/11/11 15:52:10:436 EDT] 00000014 ActionServlet E org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet handleConfigException Parsing error processing resource path 
                             java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.createSAXException(Digester.java:2792)
at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.createSAXException(Digester.java:2818)
at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1289)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1572)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.parseModuleConfigFile(ActionServlet.java:1006)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.initModuleConfig(ActionServlet.java:955)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.init(ActionServlet.java:470)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:256)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:227)
at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:341)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.initialize(ServletWrapper.java:1308)
at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.initialize(ServletWrapper.java:174)
at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.extension.WebExtensionProcessor.createServletWrapper(WebExtensionProcessor.java:99)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.getServletWrapper(WebApp.java:902)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.getServletWrapper(WebApp.java:824)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initializeTargetMappings(WebApp.java:542)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.commonInitializationFinish(WebApp.java:379)
at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initialize(WebApp.java:293)
at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.addWebApplication(WebGroup.java:93)
at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.VirtualHost.addWebApplication(VirtualHost.java:162)
at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.WebContainer.addWebApp(WebContainer.java:673)
at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.WebContainer.addWebApplication(WebContainer.java:626)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:335)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:551)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1250)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1140)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:569)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:819)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:921)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl$AppInitializer.run(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2100)
at com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl$_AsynchInitializer.run(WsComponentImpl.java:342)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1497)
---- Begin backtrace for Nested Throwables
java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:79)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:618)
at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils.setSimpleProperty(PropertyUtils.java:1789)
at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils.setNestedProperty(PropertyUtils.java:1684)
at org.apache.commons.beanutils.PropertyUtils.setProperty(PropertyUtils.java:1713)
at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils.setProperty(BeanUtils.java:1019)
at org.apache.commons.beanutils.BeanUtils.populate(BeanUtils.java:808)
at org.apache.commons.digester.SetPropertiesRule.begin(SetPropertiesRule.java:217)
at org.apache.commons.digester.Rule.begin(Rule.java:152)
at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.startElement(Digester.java:1286)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.startElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.dtd.XMLDTDValidator.startElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLNSDocumentScannerImpl.scanStartElement(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl$FragmentContentDispatcher.dispatch(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.impl.XMLDocumentFragmentScannerImpl.scanDocument(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XML11Configuration.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.XMLParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.xerces.parsers.AbstractSAXParser.parse(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.commons.digester.Digester.parse(Digester.java:1572)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.parseModuleConfigFile(ActionServlet.java:1006)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.initModuleConfig(ActionServlet.java:955)
at org.apache.struts.action.ActionServlet.init(ActionServlet.java:470)
at javax.servlet.GenericServlet.init(GenericServlet.java:256)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:227)
at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.init(ServletWrapper.java:341)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.initialize(ServletWrapper.java:1308)
at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.servlet.ServletWrapper.initialize(ServletWrapper.java:174)
at com.ibm.wsspi.webcontainer.extension.WebExtensionProcessor.createServletWrapper(WebExtensionProcessor.java:99)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.getServletWrapper(WebApp.java:902)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.getServletWrapper(WebApp.java:824)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initializeTargetMappings(WebApp.java:542)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.webapp.WebApp.commonInitializationFinish(WebApp.java:379)
at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.webapp.WebApp.initialize(WebApp.java:293)
at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.webapp.WebGroup.addWebApplication(WebGroup.java:93)
at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.VirtualHost.addWebApplication(VirtualHost.java:162)
at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.WebContainer.addWebApp(WebContainer.java:673)
at com.ibm.ws.wswebcontainer.WebContainer.addWebApplication(WebContainer.java:626)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.install(WebContainerImpl.java:335)
at com.ibm.ws.webcontainer.component.WebContainerImpl.start(WebContainerImpl.java:551)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.start(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:1250)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.fireDeployedObjectStart(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:1140)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedModuleImpl.start(DeployedModuleImpl.java:569)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.DeployedApplicationImpl.start(DeployedApplicationImpl.java:819)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl.startApplication(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:921)
at com.ibm.ws.runtime.component.ApplicationMgrImpl$AppInitializer.run(ApplicationMgrImpl.java:2100)
at com.ibm.wsspi.runtime.component.WsComponentImpl$_AsynchInitializer.run(WsComponentImpl.java:342)
at com.ibm.ws.util.ThreadPool$Worker.run(ThreadPool.java:1497)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: DynaValidatorForm
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClassImpl(Native Method)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:266)
at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:151)
at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader._defineClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:577)
at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.findClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:529)
at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:403)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:605)
at org.apache.struts.config.FormBeanConfig.formBeanClass(FormBeanConfig.java:320)
at org.apache.struts.config.FormBeanConfig.setType(FormBeanConfig.java:191)
... 50 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: DynaValidatorForm
at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.findClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:502)
at com.ibm.ws.classloader.CompoundClassLoader.loadClass(CompoundClassLoader.java:403)
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:605)
... 59 more
```

Comment: Perhaps the relevant pom snippet related to class generation as well as the stacktrace will help someone give some pointers

Answer (score 0):

I have resolved this issue.  It turns out that RAD had done an auto-build before the classpath changes had been completed, since files in the project had changed, which resulted in classes with build errors (why did it still create the class files???).  When packaging using maven, I assumed maven would recompile but instead it used these erroneous classes because everything appeared up to date.  I could have sworn I had done a "mvn clean" prior to a "mvn install" at one point to make sure this hadn't happened, with the same unfortunate results, but I could just be going crazy.